# Cassandra query language(CQL): Can we combine SELECT * FROM table_name; and SELECT count(*) FROM table_name;

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to find out if we can combine the 'Select `*`' and 'Select count`(*)`' query together in CQL and if yes, then how about the performance, does it increase the execution performance of the query than running 2 separate queries on large dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no, you can't combine these two queries.

Longer answer - don't do that.  On the big datasets your query most probably will timeout because Cassandra will need to go through all data on all machines. This will lead to increased load to coordinator node, and potentially crash it.  If you need to fetch all data you need to use another approach:

- use [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/) that is heavily optimized for such tasks
- if you want to offload data, or just count, you can use [DSBulk utility](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) for that
- if you still need to do that from the code, you need to perform so-called token range scanning - technology that is used by Spark Cassandra Connector and DSBulk.  You can either implement that yourself (here is [an example for Java driver 3.x](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java)), or for Java use DSBulk's API - the jars are available via Maven (I don't have example for that)